# catch all routes in expressjs

Tags: routes, express

I'd like to set some catch all routes in expressjs

I have three levels

> /module
>
> /module/page

If module route does not exist send to 404 route
equally if the module exists but the page doesn't send to 404 route.

404 replies in html

> /api/controller/method

As above, but 404 equivalent would reply in json

Regex is killing me so if any one can help me out my hairline would much appreciate it.
:)
I've thought of using a route look-up table but I want to try and do it the 'express' way.

Answer (score 4):

Just set up the routes for 
/module
/module/page (or maybe you wanted something like /module/:page_id)

and at the bottom of all routes you want to add

```
 app.use(function(req,res) { 
    res.render('404', 
               { locals: {'title':'Not Found'}, }, 
               function(err,str) { res.send(str,404); } );
```

if nothing matches the catch all snaps!

this is from that thread over in the google groups
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/express-js/aYLM4e1I4XU